# Scroll multiple recyclerviews on one recyclerview scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have an `arraylist` of `recyclerveiws` in another `recyclerview` and want to know how to scroll all of them when one is scrolled.
This is what I have so far, however it gives me a stack overflow error:

```
holder.rv.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dx != -199382734)
                    for (sched_vh vh : vhs) {
                        if (vh != holder)
                            vh.rv.scrollBy(-199382734, dy);
                    }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

I have worked on this problem with my friend for a few hours..the final answer is really simple.
The main idea is that two recyclerviews should use the same onscrollListener instead of different ones, so that this listener could get which recyclerview is scrolling, and avoid stack over flow. please try following

```
    //rcv and leftrcv are two recyclerviews
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (recyclerView == leftrcv) {
                rcv.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                rcv.scrollBy(0, dy);
                rcv.addOnScrollListener(this);
            } else if (recyclerView == rcv) {
                leftrcv.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                leftrcv.scrollBy(0, dy);
                leftrcv.addOnScrollListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    };

    leftrcv.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    rcv.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

But I don't know whether this will result in performance issue...

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is probably wrong. You should likely have one `RecyclerView` that has different view types.

Comment: I don't think so. I am trying to make a horizontal list of vertical lists that scrolls nicely.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems you want several vertical RecycleViews besides each other and want to horizontally scroll them.

If you want each of the vertical lists fill the screen you'd want to use a ViewPager which allows you to swipe horizontally through a list of views (or fragments).

Otherwise you could have a look at HorzizontalScrollView, though that would only make sense for a small set of vertical lists.